# How to filter IQueryable containing nullable types using expression trees?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, iqueryable

I have model class `MyModel` with a `Nullable` property: `Field1`. I'm trying to filter the queryable of `MyModel` based on `Field1` using an expression tree. The part I handle nullable is as below:

```
var memEx = Expression.Property(parameterEx, "Field1");

var memberEx = Expression.Condition(
    Expression.Property(memEx , "HasValue"),
    Expression.Property(memEx, "Value),
    ConvertExpressionType(Expression.Constant(null), typeof(TimeSpan))
)
```

Here, `ConvertExpressionType()` converts the type of the expression so that it can be used with `Condition` expression.

In debug, the full queryable looks like below:

```
{System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyModel].Where(x => ((IIF(x.Field1.HasValue, x.Field1.Value, Convert(null, TimeSpan)) + x.Field2.ToTimeSpan()) < 06:49:08.3313919))}
```

Here, `Field2` is a second field of type `long`. I'm trying to make sure the timespan sum of `Field1` and `Field2` are less than a given value.

However, when I try to enumerate the queryable, after about 2 elements, I get the `NullReferenceException`. If I just try a dummy value in expression tree instead of `null`, I can avoid it like:

```
var memEx = Expression.Property(parameterEx, "Field1");

var memberEx = Expression.Condition(
    Expression.Property(memEx , "HasValue"),
    Expression.Property(memEx, "Value),
    ConvertExpressionType(Expression.Constant(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)), typeof(TimeSpan))
)
```

So, I guess, I'm doing something wrong in the conditional expression. How can I fix this (or figure out exactly what is causing the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without even checking, I would say that the problem is

```
ConvertExpressionType(Expression.Constant(null), typeof(TimeSpan))
```

because first `null` constant has no type (`Expression.Constant(null).Type` is `typeof(object)` though) and second and more importantly, for sure cannot be converted to `TimeSpan` (or any *non nullable value type*).

It's not quite clear what does `Field1` null value mean. In case you want to treat it as zero, then replace the above with

```
Expression.Constant(TimeSpan.Zero)
```